# AWS - cannot create instance in local zone (NZ, Auckland) - keep getting non-descriptive error, logs say nothing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I changed region to Asia Pacific (Sydney), then enabled the local zone for New Zealand (Auckland) - ap-southeast-2-akl-1. I then created a new subnet 172.31.48.0/24. Then I  attempted to create a t2.micro instance (because of the free tier availability) in this new local zone. Left everything on defaults, but edited the networking options to select the new subnet I created. I keep getting this error:

*"The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations."*

Attached screenshots and full API calls. The log output in the AWS console says nothing else. Docs didn't help me identify what the problem is.

Is there a way to find out what exactly is preventing it? (too many options in the advanced config pane to try them all).

[image: new subnet]
[image: new instance]
[image]

Full API calls:

`RunInstances`

```
{
  "MaxCount": 1,
  "MinCount": 1,
  "ImageId": "ami-0373aa64534d82bf6",
  "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
  "EbsOptimized": false,
  "BlockDeviceMappings": [
    {
      "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
      "Ebs": {
        "Encrypted": false,
        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
        "SnapshotId": "snap-072aa9ed0571bf537",
        "VolumeSize": 8,
        "VolumeType": "standard"
      }
    }
  ],
  "NetworkInterfaces": [
    {
      "SubnetId": "subnet-07bc113a5718dc3fe",
      "AssociatePublicIpAddress": false,
      "DeviceIndex": 0,
      "Groups": [
        "<groupId of the new security group created below>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "TagSpecifications": [
    {
      "ResourceType": "instance",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "nz-akl-04"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "PrivateDnsNameOptions": {
    "HostnameType": "ip-name",
    "EnableResourceNameDnsARecord": false,
    "EnableResourceNameDnsAAAARecord": false
  }
}
```

`CreateSecurityGroup`

```
{
  "GroupName": "launch-wizard-5",
  "Description": "launch-wizard-5 created 2023-09-06T15:19:02.150Z",
  "VpcId": "vpc-0e5fa80171a3073df"
}
```

`AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress`

```
{
  "GroupId": "<groupId of the security group created above>",
  "IpPermissions": [
    {
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "FromPort": 22,
      "ToPort": 22,
      "IpRanges": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I checked the "Instance Types" list from the EC2 panel to show me available instances. I then clicked the gear icon to add Availability Zone to the table. It then showed that the `ap-southeast-2-akl-1` zone only had *.medium and up available instances ... no *.micro or *.nano availability.